# SQL Server database is too large when compared to actual data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

We are using SQL Server 2014. We have one database with the size of 12 GB.
I used the following query and can see the file sizes as:

```
SELECT ((size * 8)/1024), * 
FROM sys.sysfiles
```

This shows the `.mdf` file is 3 GB, `.ldf` file is 9 GB.

Then I used the following query to see the actual tables size:

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    i.name as indexName,
    p.[Rows],
    SUM(a.total_pages) as TotalPages, 
    SUM(a.used_pages) as UsedPages, 
    SUM(a.data_pages) as DataPages,
    (SUM(a.total_pages) * 8) / 1024 as TotalSpaceMB, 
    (SUM(a.used_pages) * 8) / 1024 as UsedSpaceMB, 
    (SUM(a.data_pages) * 8) / 1024 as DataSpaceMB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' AND
    i.OBJECT_ID > 255 AND   
    i.index_id <= 1
GROUP BY 
    t.NAME, i.object_id, i.index_id, i.name, p.[Rows]
ORDER BY 
    5 desc
```

This shows the total size is just 40 MB.

But, we are wondering what is occupying the remaining space of 3 GB in the `.mdf` file.

Please help us to find out the objects the objects that are taking so much space in mdf and ldf files.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Are you in full recovery mode? Do you have any kind of maintenance on the database? Why did you exclude certain objects in your query? If you want the total size you should not exclude objects. Sounds like the transaction logs are quite large and not being maintained.

Comment: Check how much of the database is actually used. You can do that from a database's properties window, or the [sp_spaceused](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/display-data-and-log-space-information-for-a-database) stored procedure. Either you are missing tables or you loaded a lot of data at some point and then deleted it. The size of the log file definitelly shows that it wasn't backed up for quite some time

Comment: Hi Sean Lange, I have included all objects and tried again. still it shows the same size. And the database recovery mode is set to "Simple".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the predefined stored procedure of "sp_spaceused" to check how much space your database is using.

```
USE <database_name>
EXEC sp_spaceused
```

It will generate an output that looks like this...

[image]

The database name is displayed in the first column of the first row.

Note that...

database_size = reserved space + unallocated space + log space

sp_spaceused does NOT display the log space amount, but this can be calculated from the results generated by sp_spaceused.

Refer to this [DataRinger.com page](https://dataginger.com/2013/06/28/sql-server-understanding-sp_spaceused-results-for-database-size-information/) on sp_spaceused for more details.

The following image from this page depicts the different SQL Server areas that make up the overall database size.

[image]

I suspect that your database's transaction log file is what is taking up the unaccounted for space in your database.

["Manage the Size of the Transaction Log File"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/manage-the-size-of-the-transaction-log-file) is a Microsoft page that provides information about the log file.  This may help you with your database.

Comment: I tried "sp_spaceused", but this also returning the same results.that is its showing the data as 40MB approximately.

Comment: What value was listed under the "index_size" column heading?

Comment: reserved  : 65288 KB, data:57648 KB, index_size: 3224 KB, unused:             4416 KB

Comment: Please review the new content added to my answer. I hope this helps.